# How to add "AS" for alias support into ANTLR Lex file of MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, antlr

Using this lex file:
https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/mysql/MySQLLexer.g4

When I process this statement:

```
    String sql = "select x as gorp from FOO ";
```

I get this:
**line 1:12 extraneous input 'gorp' expecting {, 'from', 'where', ','}**

I looked in the lex file listed above and there is no definition for AS.

How do I make the ANTLR lex and grammar definition files work with MySQL SELECT statements that have the "AS" keyword in them?

Comment: This is opinion-based. No one knows why except the original developer. Consider emailing him.

Comment: @Michael I think most developers understand my point.

Comment: what is the question here?

Comment: @eis The question is "how do I make the ANTLR lex and grammar definition files work with MySQL SELECT statements that have the "AS" keyword in them?"

Comment: @nicomp ok, fixed the question to say that

Answer (score 2):

The parser does not know the `as` keyword. In mysql, this can be omitted.

The parser definition for the column is :

> column_name
>      : ( ( schema_name DOT )? ID DOT )? ID **( column_name_alias )?** | ( table_alias DOT )? ID | USER_VAR ( column_name_alias )?
>      ;

So just remove the "as" keyword.

---

**Fix attempt:** Alternatively, change the g4 files

In *MySQLLexer.g4*, append

```
AS
 : 'as'
 ;
```

And in the *MySQLParser.g4*, update the column name definition

```
column_name : ( ( schema_name DOT )? ID DOT )? ID ( ( AS )? column_name_alias )? | ( table_alias DOT )? ID | USER_VAR ( ( AS )? column_name_alias )? ;
```

And ideally the table definition that can have an alias too

```
table_atom : ( table_name ( partition_clause )? ( ( AS )? table_alias )? ( index_hint_list )? ) | ( subquery subquery_alias ) | ( LPAREN table_references RPAREN ) | ( OJ table_reference LEFT OUTER JOIN table_reference ON expression ) ;
```

Comment: Well, it can be omitted but it also can be included. The parser fails if it is included. What would I add to the g4 file?

Comment: Edited to include the changed to the g4 files.

Comment: Didn't work. It interpreted the word AS as the alias.

Comment: I do not know the operator precedence of the parser. Would it be OK for you to make the `as` keyword mandatory ?

Comment: I need to be able to handle syntactically valid MySQL statements from any source. I'm sad that the g4 file isn't comprehensive but beggars can't be choosers.

Comment: Can you try : `column_name : ( ( ( schema_name DOT )? ID DOT )? ID ( AS column_name_alias )? ) | ( ( table_alias DOT )? ID ( AS column_name_alias )? ) | ( USER_VAR ( AS column_name_alias )? ) | ( ( ( schema_name DOT )? ID DOT )? ID ( column_name_alias )? ) | ( ( table_alias DOT )? ID ( column_name_alias )? ) | ( USER_VAR ( column_name_alias )? ) ;` Weanwhile, there are many more fixes to bring to support all syntaxically correct mysql statements... This should probably be posed as an issue on the GIT repository.

Answer (score 2):

The MySQL in the grammar repository is just a very simple variant, missing many many things of that language. Instead try my ANTLR3 grammar: https://github.com/mysql/mysql-workbench/tree/master/library/parsers/grammars and adjust it for ANTLR4. This one is 100% complete.

Comment: Is there a guide for 'adjusting' for ANTLR 4?

Comment: I think It won't generate Java. The generated source code must be in C, right?

Comment: Adjustment of the grammar is pretty simple. Just follow what the ANTLR4 tool is telling you. The grammar is made for the ANTLR3 C target, right, but it should be easy to convert that small C code to Java. You can also start by remove all target code and let your compiler tell you what's missing. Then add functions modeled after what's in the grammar.